How make ScrollView dragable with drag in macOS SwiftUI?
I have a scrollview in macOS SwiftUI, it is scrollable just with scrolling on the view, how ever I am unable to scroll with mouse drag, dragging up or down does not make scrollview scrolled. Should I enable some option to be able to do this? I think in past I had no issue with this, and maybe it is a new thing.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            MyView()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame(height: 100.0)
                    .cornerRadius(5.0)
            }

        }
        
    }
}

update:


Very impressive. I did several tests and none of them worked. The same code works on iOS but not on MacOS. Draggin only works on the scrollbar but does not work on rectangles.

This code working good on iOS, you can scroll the view with drag, but in macOS does not, I remember in past that I had no issue, but now I cannot scroll it with drag.

Huh? Was there ever a time when you can drag a scroll view on macOS? I know you can do that with the Apple Maps app, but that's a map, not a scroll view.

@Sweeper: I add the scroll with drag video
